# How an End user login into a console

Tags: console

Hi i am learnig salesforce how an end user login into a console which maybe a sevice or sales console

Comment: What do u mean by "end user login"?

Comment: which is the question i encountered in one my interview

Comment: I personally feel it is inappropriate to ask interview or exam questions on Salesforce Stack Exchange. This community can provide assistance to supplement your own skills and research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to the console apps which by definition are:

> Salesforce Console apps are a tab-based workspace suited for fast-paced work environments. Manage multiple records on a single screen and reduce time spent clicking and scrolling to quickly find, update, and create records.

You can create either Sales or Service console apps based on your business needs and accordingly provide Users access to these apps. There is no specific permission required but only that whoever needs access to the app should have that available on their profile or permission set.

More details on console apps can be found [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=console2_about.htm&type=5) on the help article.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a [Service Cloud Console](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=console2_setting_up_serviceconsole.htm&r=https:%2F%2Fwww.google.no%2F&type=5) and provide access to your end users. Once this is done, end users can login to Salesforce and choose "Console".